# Android performance issue with "pathPrecache" consuming a lot of time once per 400~500 ms

Tags: android, performance, canvas

I have a simple game application that uses Android canvas API to draw the whole scene. However, my game have performance issue with the following symptoms:

- The game runs smoothly at the beginning.
- After a while (about 30s), a noticable frame-drop once per 400~500 ms begins to occur regularly. One frame-drop becomes longer and longer with time. And if I left the game to run for 5 minutes, one frame-drop would be as long as a second, which makes the game not playable.
- The 20~30 frames between two consecutive frame-drops are smooth.
- With the systrace tool, I found that the frame-drop is caused by RenderThread being blocked in the "waitForTask" method of "flush drawing commands" phase. Meanwhile a "pathPrecache" with almost 100% CPU time / wall time ratio is running on a third thread other than main thread and render thread.
- Reproducable on all test devices I have access to.

What is the "pathPrecache" doing? I can find its source here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0f809f3/libs/hwui/PathCache.cpp . It seems that this task is trying to pre-cache the rasterized result of canvas drawPath() calls into a PathTexture object. My game scene does contain some drawPath() calls (and also drawRect() calls which are actually drawPath() too). But each frame are totally independent and the whole scene is redrawn. What makes it that the work for pathPrecache is becoming cumulatively heavier with time? Is there any way to disable the pathPrecache feature?

```
public class GameScene extends View {

    private static final String TAG = GameScene.class.getSimpleName();

    // ... Debug flags ...

    // ... Color constants ...

    // ... Dimension calculation constants ...

    private GameState mState;

    private Paint mBeltPaint;
    private Paint mActiveZonePaint;
    private Paint mDividerPaint;
    private Paint mBorderLinePaint;
    private Paint mBorderLineOuterPaint;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    private Bitmap mActiveZoneShaderBitmap;
    private Bitmap mBorderLightBitmapLeft;
    private Bitmap mBorderLightBitmapRight;

    private Arm mArm;

    private Projector mPrj;

    private float mBannerHeight;

    private final float mDividerWidth;
    private final float mLargeBoxWidth;
    private final float mSmallBoxWidth;
    private final float mBombWidth;
    private final float mArmBottomOffsetUp;
    private final float mBorderOffsetInner;
    private final float mBorderOffsetOuter;
    private final float mEmptyCatchTranslationY;

    /**
     * Manually maintains two software drawing caches containing the game board for performance.
     */
    private DrawingCacheInfo[] mBoardCaches;

    private static final int DRAW_COMPONENT_BELT = 0;
    private static final int DRAW_COMPONENT_BORDER_LIGHTS = 1;

    // ... Pre-allocated objects (Rect, etc.) ...

    private long mLastDrawTime;

    public GameScene(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Resources res = context.getResources();

        mBeltPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBeltPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBeltPaint.setDither(true);

        mDividerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mDividerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mDividerPaint.setDither(true);

        mActiveZonePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        mActiveZonePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mBorderLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBorderLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(res.getDimension(R.dimen.lucky_game_border_line_width));
        mBorderLinePaint.setColor(BORDER_LINE_COLOR);

        mBorderLineOuterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBorderLineOuterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderLineOuterPaint.setStrokeWidth(res.getDimension(R.dimen.lucky_game_border_outer_line_width));
        mBorderLineOuterPaint.setColor(BORDER_OUTER_LINE_COLOR);

        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        // ... Dimensions initialization ...

        // ... Bitmaps initialization ...
    }

    public void setState(GameState state) {
        mState = state;
    }

    public void setBannerHeight(int bannerHeight) {
        mBannerHeight = bannerHeight;

        int viewWidth = getWidth();
        int viewHeight = getHeight();
        int boardHeight = viewHeight - bannerHeight;
        mPrj = new Projector(bannerHeight, viewWidth, boardHeight);

        mBoardCaches = new DrawingCacheInfo[] {
                new DrawingCacheInfo(viewWidth, boardHeight, DRAW_COMPONENT_BELT),
                new DrawingCacheInfo(viewWidth, boardHeight, DRAW_COMPONENT_BORDER_LIGHTS)};

        mArm = new Arm(getContext(), bannerHeight * (1f - ARM_TOP_OFFSET_RATIO));

        Shader beltShader = new LinearGradient(0f, bannerHeight, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight,
                BELT_COLOR_FAR, BELT_COLOR_NEAR, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mBeltPaint.setShader(beltShader);

        Shader dividerShader = new LinearGradient(0f, bannerHeight, 0f, viewHeight,
                DIVIDER_COLOR_FAR, DIVIDER_COLOR_NEAR, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mDividerPaint.setShader(dividerShader);

        Shader activeZoneShader = new BitmapShader(mActiveZoneShaderBitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mActiveZonePaint.setShader(activeZoneShader);

        // Heat up drawing cache in advance to avoid first-frame jitter in animation
        buildDrawingCache(mBoardCaches[0]);
        buildDrawingCache(mBoardCaches[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mPrj == null) {
            HSLog.i(TAG, "Projector not initialized, skip drawing");
            return;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (PROFILE) {
            profile();
        }

        drawGameBoard(canvas);

        // Draw all targets except one in catch animation. The drawing of this target is deferred until arm is drawn.
        PendingTarget pendingTarget = drawTargets(canvas);

        // Draw the arm. Report pulled-up distance of the target being caught.
        float pullUpY = drawArm(canvas, pendingTarget);

        if (pendingTarget != null) {
            // The the pending target, if there is one.
            drawPendingTarget(canvas, pendingTarget, -pullUpY);
        }
    }

    private void drawGameBoard(Canvas canvas) {
        for (DrawingCacheInfo cacheInfo : mBoardCaches) {
            if (cacheInfo.hasBuilt) {
                // Draw from cache
                GameState.CatchAnimator catchAnim = mState.getCatchAnimator();
                if (cacheInfo.component != DRAW_COMPONENT_BORDER_LIGHTS || catchAnim == null) {
                    mBitmapPaint.setAlpha(0xff);
                } else {
                    float alpha = catchAnim.getBorderLightAlpha();
                    mBitmapPaint.setAlpha((int) (0xff * alpha));
                }
                float revealRatio = 1f;
                if (cacheInfo.component == DRAW_COMPONENT_BORDER_LIGHTS) {
                    revealRatio = mState.getBorderLightsRevealRatio();
                }
                mRect.set(0, 0, cacheInfo.cache.getWidth(),
                        (int) (revealRatio * cacheInfo.cache.getHeight()));
                mRectF.set(0, mBannerHeight, cacheInfo.cache.getWidth(),
                        mBannerHeight + revealRatio * cacheInfo.cache.getHeight());
                canvas.drawBitmap(cacheInfo.cache, mRect, mRectF, mBitmapPaint);
            } else {
                buildDrawingCache(cacheInfo);

                // Draw directly to on-screen canvas
                performDrawBoardComponent(canvas, cacheInfo.component, false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void buildDrawingCache(DrawingCacheInfo cacheInfo) {
        if (cacheInfo.enabled) {
            Canvas cacheCanvas = new Canvas(cacheInfo.cache);
            cacheCanvas.translate(0, -mBannerHeight);

            // Draw to cache
            performDrawBoardComponent(cacheCanvas, cacheInfo.component, true);
            cacheInfo.hasBuilt = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param cacheDraw {@code true} if we're drawing to cache bitmap, {@code false} if we're drawing to screen.
     */
    private void performDrawBoardComponent(Canvas canvas, int which, boolean cacheDraw) {
        switch (which) {
            case DRAW_COMPONENT_BELT:
                performDrawBelt(canvas);
                break;
            case DRAW_COMPONENT_BORDER_LIGHTS:
                performDrawBorderLights(canvas, cacheDraw);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void performDrawBelt(Canvas canvas) {
        GameConfig config = mState.getConfig();
        float activeRowIndex = config.getActiveRowIndex();
        int trackCount = config.getTrackCount();
        int rowCount = config.getRowCount();
        float toleranceV = config.getCatchToleranceVertical();

        int viewWidth = getWidth();
        int viewHeight = getHeight();

        // Draw belt color
        mRectF.set(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        mPrj.drawRect(canvas, mRectF, mBeltPaint);

        // Draw track dividers
        float perTrackWidth = getWidth() / (float) trackCount;
        for (int i = 1; i < trackCount; i++) {
            float dividerX = i * perTrackWidth;
            mRectF.set(dividerX - mDividerWidth / 2, 0, dividerX + mDividerWidth / 2, viewHeight);
            mPrj.drawRect(canvas, mRectF, mDividerPaint);
        }

        // Draw active zone
        float activeZoneTop = ((activeRowIndex - 0.5f - 0.5f * toleranceV) / (float) rowCount) * viewHeight;
        float activeZoneBottom = ((activeRowIndex - 0.5f + 0.5f * toleranceV) / (float) rowCount) * viewHeight;
        mRectF.set(0, activeZoneTop, viewWidth, activeZoneBottom);
        mPrj.drawRect(canvas, mRectF, mActiveZonePaint, mActiveZoneShaderBitmap);

        // Draw border lines
        mPrj.drawLine(canvas, -mBorderOffsetOuter, 0f, -mBorderOffsetOuter, viewHeight, mBorderLinePaint);
        mPrj.drawLine(canvas, -mBorderOffsetInner, 0f, -mBorderOffsetInner, viewHeight, mBorderLinePaint);
        mPrj.drawLine(canvas, viewWidth + mBorderOffsetInner, 0f, viewWidth + mBorderOffsetInner, viewHeight, mBorderLinePaint);
        mPrj.drawLine(canvas, viewWidth + mBorderOffsetOuter, 0f, viewWidth + mBorderOffsetOuter, viewHeight, mBorderLinePaint);
        mRectF.set(-mBorderOffsetOuter - mBorderOffsetInner, 0f, 0f, viewHeight);
        mPrj.drawRect(canvas, mRectF, mBorderLineOuterPaint);
        mRectF.set(viewWidth, 0f, viewWidth + mBorderOffsetOuter + mBorderOffsetInner, viewHeight);
        mPrj.drawRect(canvas, mRectF, mBorderLineOuterPaint);
    }

    private void performDrawBorderLights(Canvas canvas, boolean cacheDraw) {
        int lightCount = mState.getConfig().getBorderLightCount();
        int viewWidth = getWidth();
        int viewHeight = getHeight();

        float lightWidth = 4 * (mBorderOffsetOuter - mBorderOffsetInner);
        float lightHeight = lightWidth * ((float) mBorderLightBitmapLeft.getHeight() / mBorderLightBitmapLeft.getWidth());

        GameState.CatchAnimator catchAnim = mState.getCatchAnimator();
        if (cacheDraw || catchAnim == null) {
            mBitmapPaint.setAlpha(0xff);
        } else {
            float alpha = catchAnim.getBorderLightAlpha();
            mBitmapPaint.setAlpha((int) (0xff * alpha));
        }

        float revealRatio = 1f;
        if (!cacheDraw) { // For cache building, draw all lights regardless of current reveal ratio
            revealRatio = mState.getBorderLightsRevealRatio();
        }
        for (int i = 1, n = (int) (lightCount * revealRatio); i <= n; i++) {
            float lightX = -(mBorderOffsetInner + mBorderOffsetOuter) / 2f;
            float lightY = ((float) i / lightCount) * viewHeight;
            mRectF.set(lightX - lightWidth / 2f, lightY - lightHeight / 2f,
                    lightX + lightWidth / 2f, lightY + lightHeight / 2f);
            mPrj.drawBitmap(canvas, mBorderLightBitmapLeft, mRectF, mBitmapPaint);
            lightX = viewWidth + (mBorderOffsetInner + mBorderOffsetOuter) / 2f;
            mRectF.set(lightX - lightWidth / 2f, lightY - lightHeight / 2f,
                    lightX + lightWidth / 2f, lightY + lightHeight / 2f);
            mPrj.drawBitmap(canvas, mBorderLightBitmapRight, mRectF, mBitmapPaint);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draw all targets of current game state except the one in catch animation.
     *
     * @return Drawing info of the target currently in catch animation. Or null.
     */
    private PendingTarget drawTargets(Canvas canvas) {
        List<TargetInfo> targets = mState.getTargets();
        PendingTarget pendingTarget = null;
        for (TargetInfo target : targets) {
            if (target.hasFlag(TargetInfo.FLAG_CAUGHT)) {
                continue;
            }
            mapTargetCoordinates(target, mCoords, mBitmapPaint);

            Bitmap bitmap = target.getBitmap();

            float halfWidth = 0f, halfHeight, up, down;
            switch (target.type) {
                case LARGE_BOX:
                    halfWidth = mLargeBoxWidth / 2f;
                    break;
                case SMALL_BOX:
                    halfWidth = mSmallBoxWidth / 2f;
                    break;
                case BOMB:
                    halfWidth = mBombWidth / 2f;
                    break;
            }
            // ... Some calculations ...
            if (target.hasFlag(TargetInfo.FLAG_IN_CATCH_ANIMATION)) {
                if (pendingTarget != null) {
                    throw new GameException("Multiple targets in catching animation: "
                            + target.trackIndex + ", " + target.translation);
                }
                pendingTarget = new PendingTarget(target, bitmap, new RectF(mRectF));
            } else {
                mPrj.drawBitmap(canvas, bitmap, mRectF, mBitmapPaint);
            }
        }
        return pendingTarget;
    }

    private void drawPendingTarget(Canvas canvas, PendingTarget target, float offsetY) {
        mBitmapPaint.setAlpha(0xff);
        mPrj.drawBitmap(canvas, target.bitmap, target.bounds, offsetY, mBitmapPaint);
    }

    private static class PendingTarget {
        TargetInfo target;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        RectF bounds;

        PendingTarget(TargetInfo target, Bitmap bitmap, RectF bounds) {
            this.target = target;
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            this.bounds = bounds;
        }
    }

    private float drawArm(Canvas canvas, PendingTarget preyTarget) {
        GameConfig config = mState.getConfig();
        float activeRowIndex = config.getActiveRowIndex();
        int trackCount = config.getTrackCount();
        int rowCount = config.getRowCount();
        float toleranceV = config.getCatchToleranceVertical();

        // ... Some calculations ...

        mInCoord[0] = armX;
        mInCoord[1] = activeZoneCenterY;
        mPrj.projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
        float prjCenterX = mOutCoord[0];

        mInCoord[1] = activeZoneTopY;
        mPrj.projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
        float prjActiveZoneTopY = mOutCoord[1];

        GameState.CatchAnimator catchAnim = mState.getCatchAnimator();
        float closeAngle = handleCatchAnimation(prjCenterX, prjActiveZoneTopY + mArmBottomOffsetUp, preyTarget,
                catchAnim, mOutCoord, mOutVal);
        mArm.draw(canvas, mOutCoord[0], mOutCoord[1], closeAngle);

        return mOutVal[0];
    }

    /**
     * @param paint Paint used to draw this {@code target}. It's alpha would be set in this method based on distance.
     */
    private void mapTargetCoordinates(TargetInfo target, int[] outCoord, Paint paint) {
        GameConfig config = mState.getConfig();
        int trackCount = config.getTrackCount();
        int rowCount = config.getRowCount();

        float trackIndex = extendHorizontalPosition(target.trackIndex);
        float translation = target.translation;

        outCoord[0] = (int) (((trackIndex + 0.5f) / (float) trackCount) * getWidth());
        outCoord[1] = (int) (((translation - 0.5f) / (float) rowCount) * getHeight());
        float alphaUnclamped = TARGET_ALPHA_FAR +
                (1f - TARGET_ALPHA_FAR) * (translation / rowCount) / TARGET_OPAQUE_POSITION_RATIO;
        float alpha = Math.max(0f, Math.min(alphaUnclamped, 1f));
        paint.setAlpha((int) (0xff * alpha));
    }

    private float extendHorizontalPosition(float rawPosition) {
        int span = mState.getConfig().getTrackCount() - 1;
        return rawPosition * (span + 2 * HORIZONTAL_POSITION_EXTENSION) / span
                - HORIZONTAL_POSITION_EXTENSION;
    }

    public void release() {
        if (mActiveZoneShaderBitmap != null) {
            mActiveZoneShaderBitmap = null;
        }

        if (mBorderLightBitmapLeft != null) {
            mBorderLightBitmapLeft = null;
        }

        if (mBorderLightBitmapRight != null) {
            mBorderLightBitmapRight = null;
        }
    }

    private static class Arm {
        private static final int HAND_LEFT = 0;
        private static final int HAND_RIGHT = 1;

        /** Hands' angle to vertical position at normal open status, in radians (about 16 degrees) */
        private static final float HAND_OPEN_ANGLE_RADIANS = 0.281f;

        private Drawable mBody;
        private Drawable mLeftHand;
        private Drawable mRightHand;

        private final float mTop;

        private final float mHandPivotY;
        private final float mLeftHandInstallX;
        private final float mRightHandInstallX;
        private final float mHandsInstallY;

        Arm(Context context, float top) {
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            mHandPivotY = res.getDimension(R.dimen.lucky_game_arm_hand_pivot_y);
            mLeftHandInstallX = res.getDimension(R.dimen.lucky_game_arm_left_hand_install_x);
            mRightHandInstallX = res.getDimension(R.dimen.lucky_game_arm_right_hand_install_x);
            mHandsInstallY = res.getDimension(R.dimen.lucky_game_arm_hands_install_y);

            mBody = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.lucky_arm_body);
            Bitmap rightHandBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.lucky_arm_hand);
            mRightHand = new BitmapDrawable(res, rightHandBitmap);
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.setScale(-1f, 1f);
            Bitmap leftHandBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rightHandBitmap, 0, 0,
                    rightHandBitmap.getWidth(), rightHandBitmap.getHeight(), m, false);
            mLeftHand = new BitmapDrawable(res, leftHandBitmap);

            mTop = top;
        }

        void draw(Canvas canvas, float centerX, float bottom, float closeAngleRadians) {
            int width = mBody.getIntrinsicWidth();
            mBody.setBounds((int) centerX - width / 2, (int) mTop, (int) centerX + width / 2, (int) bottom);
            mBody.draw(canvas);

            drawHand(canvas, HAND_LEFT, closeAngleRadians);
            drawHand(canvas, HAND_RIGHT, closeAngleRadians);
        }

        private void drawHand(Canvas canvas, int which, float closeAngleRadians) {
            float isLeft = (which == HAND_LEFT ? 1f : -1f);
            float drawAngle = isLeft * (HAND_OPEN_ANGLE_RADIANS - closeAngleRadians);
            Rect bodyBounds = mBody.getBounds();
            float pivotX = bodyBounds.left + (which == HAND_LEFT ? mLeftHandInstallX : mRightHandInstallX);
            float pivotY = bodyBounds.bottom - mHandsInstallY;

            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate((float) Math.toDegrees(drawAngle), pivotX, pivotY);
            Drawable drawable = (which == HAND_LEFT ? mLeftHand : mRightHand);
            drawable.setBounds(
                    (int) (pivotX - mRightHand.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2f),
                    (int) (pivotY - mHandPivotY),
                    (int) (pivotX + mRightHand.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2f),
                    (int) (pivotY + (mRightHand.getIntrinsicHeight() - mHandPivotY)));
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes drawing commands and projects objects in [0, 0 - width, height] to a perspective position.
     */
    private class Projector {
        private static final float PROJECTION_RATIO_FAR = 0.426f;
        private static final float PROJECTION_RATIO_NEAR = 1.095f;

        private int mTopBanner;
        private int mWidth;
        private int mHeight;

        private Path mPath = new Path();
        private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

        Projector(int topBanner, int width, int height) {
            mTopBanner = topBanner;
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight = height;
        }

        void drawRect(Canvas canvas, RectF rect, @NonNull Paint paint) {
            drawRect(canvas, rect, paint, null);
        }

        void drawRect(Canvas canvas, RectF rect, @NonNull Paint paint, @Nullable Bitmap shaderBitmap) {
            // Outer RECTANGLE bounds AFTER projection, used to process shader on the paint
            float left, top, right, bottom;

            mPath.reset();

            mInCoord[0] = rect.left;
            mInCoord[1] = rect.top;
            projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
            mPath.moveTo(mOutCoord[0], mOutCoord[1]);
            top = mOutCoord[1];

            mInCoord[0] = rect.left;
            mInCoord[1] = rect.bottom;
            projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
            mPath.lineTo(mOutCoord[0], mOutCoord[1]);
            left = mOutCoord[0];
            bottom = mOutCoord[1];

            mInCoord[0] = rect.right;
            mInCoord[1] = rect.bottom;
            projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
            mPath.lineTo(mOutCoord[0], mOutCoord[1]);
            right = mOutCoord[0];

            mInCoord[0] = rect.right;
            mInCoord[1] = rect.top;
            projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
            mPath.lineTo(mOutCoord[0], mOutCoord[1]);

            mPath.close();

            // Translate and scale bitmap shader on the paint (if set) to proper position
            if (shaderBitmap != null && paint.getShader() instanceof BitmapShader) {
                BitmapShader shader = (BitmapShader) paint.getShader();
                mMatrix.setTranslate(left, top);

                float scaleX = (right - left) / shaderBitmap.getWidth();
                float scaleY = (bottom - top) / shaderBitmap.getHeight();
                mMatrix.preScale(scaleX, scaleY);

                shader.setLocalMatrix(mMatrix);
            }

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
        }

        void drawLine(Canvas canvas, float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, @NonNull Paint paint) {
            mInCoord[0] = startX;
            mInCoord[1] = startY;
            projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
            startX = mOutCoord[0];
            startY = mOutCoord[1];

            mInCoord[0] = stopX;
            mInCoord[1] = stopY;
            projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
            stopX = mOutCoord[0];
            stopY = mOutCoord[1];

            canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
        }

        /**
         * Draw with position projection and scale only. Aspect ratio is not altered. Bitmap is considered to have a
         * perspective look itself and hence is not twisted.
         */
        void drawBitmap(Canvas canvas, @NonNull Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull RectF dst, @Nullable Paint paint) {
            drawBitmap(canvas, bitmap, dst, 0f, paint);
        }

        /**
         * Draw with position projection and scale only. Aspect ratio is not altered. Bitmap is considered to have a
         * perspective look itself and hence is not twisted.
         *
         * @param offsetY Offset Y AFTER projection.
         */
        void drawBitmap(Canvas canvas, @NonNull Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull RectF dst, float offsetY, @Nullable Paint paint) {
            // Project rect center
            mInCoord[0] = (dst.left + dst.right) / 2f;
            mInCoord[1] = (dst.top + dst.bottom) / 2f;
            float halfWidth = mInCoord[0] - dst.left;
            float halfHeight = mInCoord[1] - dst.top;
            float ratio = projectPoint(mInCoord, mOutCoord);
            float centerX = mOutCoord[0];
            float centerY = mOutCoord[1] + offsetY;

            mRectF.set(centerX - halfWidth * ratio, centerY - halfHeight * ratio,
                    centerX + halfWidth * ratio, centerY + halfHeight * ratio);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, mRectF, paint);
        }

        float projectPoint(float[] inCoord, float[] outCoord) {
            if (DEBUG_PROJECTION) {
                outCoord[0] = inCoord[0];
                outCoord[1] = inCoord[1];
                return 1f;
            }
            float x = inCoord[0];
            float y = inCoord[1];

            float yRelative = perspective(y / (mTopBanner + mHeight));
            float projectionRatio = PROJECTION_RATIO_FAR
                    + yRelative * (PROJECTION_RATIO_NEAR - PROJECTION_RATIO_FAR);
            float centerX = mWidth / 2f;

            outCoord[0] = centerX + projectionRatio * (x - centerX);
            outCoord[1] = mTopBanner + yRelative * mHeight;

            return projectionRatio;
        }

        /**
         * [0, 1] -> [0, 1] mapping function that adjust Y value to make difference in distance looks real.
         */
        private float perspective(float p) {
            final float coefSum = PROJECTION_RATIO_NEAR + PROJECTION_RATIO_FAR;
            return ((PROJECTION_RATIO_NEAR - PROJECTION_RATIO_FAR) / coefSum) * p * p
                    + (2 * PROJECTION_RATIO_FAR / coefSum) * p;
        }
    }

    private static class DrawingCacheInfo {
        /** Whether the cache is enabled. Cache is disabled if OutOfMemory error occurs with memory allocation. */
        boolean enabled = true;

        boolean hasBuilt = false;
        Bitmap cache;

        /**
         * Which component of game board this drawing cache is holding.
         * Must be one of {@link #DRAW_COMPONENT_BELT}, {@link #DRAW_COMPONENT_BORDER_LIGHTS}.
         * */
        int component;

        DrawingCacheInfo(int width, int height, int whichComponent) {
            try {
                cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                HSLog.w(TAG, "Out of memory while trying to allocate drawing cache, disable cache");
                enabled = false;
            }
            component = whichComponent;
        }
    }

    private static class GameException extends RuntimeException {
        GameException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without code, there's no way anyone could tell what's going on. Provide the smallest possible reproducible code.

Comment: I pasted the class. Sorry for the length, I've already removed some irrelavant code and kept all code that set paints and perform drawing.